# grDevices::dev.new() does not work in the first time

Tags: r, plot

**My question:** How to let `grDevices::dev.new()` work well ?

*To avoid the error* `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large` coursing the small plot region,
 I wrote the code  `grDevices::dev.new()` in the front of `plot()`.
 However this code does not work in the first time (or after pushing the button `.clean all plot` button )

And this cause the errors (e.g., in the R CMD check).

Do I  misunderstand the function  `grDevices::dev.new()` ?

[image]

REF?:
[R: Open new graphic device with dev.new() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499611/r-open-new-graphic-device-with-dev-new-does-not-work)

---

**Answer**

Using `grDevices::windows()` instead of `grDevices::dev.new()`, I overcome the issues.

---

Unfortunately, we cannot use `grDevices::windows()` , because the following error occurs in the `R CMD check`:

```
  Error in grDevices::windows() : 
     screen devices should not be used in examples etc
```

---